# Scripting an alert

Tags: shell

I've a data as follows in the text file.

```
source_table_name             | last_run_timestamp  | freq_in_secs
------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------

                    table1 | 08/19/2019 14:30:27 |  300
                    table2 | 08/19/2019 14:30:26 |  600 
                    table3 | 08/19/2019 13:40:21 | 3660
```

I want to send an alert if `last_run_timestamp + freq_in_secs + 1200 secs > current timestamp` then shoot an alert.
I will have 100 rows like this in the file. I will have to read this file , do above calculation and then send alert using shell script.

Comment: Does your file include all that header ascii art?

Comment: Are those timestamps using UTC or local time?

Comment: A part of the solution seems to be [here](https://community.hpe.com/t5/General/Calculate-time-difference-in-Unix-shell-script/m-p/2861734/highlight/true#M59906)!

Comment: yes header is included.

Comment: timestamp are local time.